# HDF5DotNet package import from nuget in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, nuget, hdf5dotnet

I'm trying to add `HDF5DotNet` to my Unity project. I've downloaded the package from `Nuget`, extracted it after changing it to Zip. Then I copied the `dll` file to the Plugins directory in the Assets directory inside my project.

However, when I try to run my project, I still obtain the following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'HDF5DotNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if you have imported the required file into your file?

If not, let try the following

```
import HDF5DotNet
```

Thanks
ANS

Comment: I'm importing it with `using  HDF5DotNet;` , I tried with `import  HDF5DotNet;` but it's not recognised in C# , thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You have copied the DLL files to your project directory, but do you need to add them as a DLL entry in any configuration file? I'm just suggesting you generally. I remember we used to add the library packages entry in a configuration file as well, so that compiler can pick them while compiling the code.